# Events in Substrate Archive

Tags: substrate-archive, archive

Does substrate archive store events anywhere? It doesn't seems like it does, although it saves extrinsics and its parameters.

I'm also having this kind of issue when running the app with a custom archive.toml

```
[09:02] INFO Open RocksDB at /var/folders/19/5tshxn412wx071h968j4s3s00000gn/T/substrate6CfgCx/chains/dev/db/full, state column budget: 115 MiB, others(11) column cache: 1 MiB
Error: Backend error: Unexpected Error: RuntimeCode("`:code` hash not found")

Caused by:
    Unexpected Error: RuntimeCode("`:code` hash not found")
```

The only way to make it work has been by relaunching it until it starts to process the data. Has anyone faced this kind of issue?

Comment: I think your second question is outside the scope of the original post.  There's an open issue here for that: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive/issues/449 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in this [open issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive/issues/136), storing events is a feature that's yet to be implemented. Since this current version was released before type-decoding (metadata V14) was a thing, it doesn't differentiate from different types of storage.

> With type-decoding we can differentiate based on the pallet an entry came from/particular transaction names/etc and it would then be trivial to allow a user to enter a set of pallets or entries they want and not index anything else.

Something we'll hopefully see in the near future.